# Multiple class inheritance with undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby, class, oop, inheritance, methods

I am attempting to create a ruby app to prompt the user to enter their favorite athlete. Then I will be prompting the user to be more specific on the their sport athlete. I also want to display the input with a specific string.

```
class Player
  attr_accessor :name

  def plays
    "#{name} plays sports!"
  end
end

class NFL < Player
  def plays
    "#{name} plays Footbal!"
  end
end

class NBA < Player
  def plays
    "#{name} plays Basketball!"
  end
end

athlete = Player.new
puts "Who is your favorite athlete?"
athlete.name = gets.chomp
puts athlete.plays

athlete2 = Player.new
puts "Who is your favorite NBA star?"
athlete2.name = get.chomp
puts athlete2.plays
```

Runtime:

```
Who is your favorite athlete?
Russell Wilson
Russell Wilson plays sports!
Who is your favorite NBA star?

OOP.rb:29:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `get' for ma
in:Object (NameError)
```

I am guessing I have something wrong in the calling of the sub-class method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
 athlete2.name = get.chomp # you mistyped it.It is not `get`, rather `Kernel#gets`.
```

to

```
 athlete2.name = gets.chomp
```